# Creating an Animation when DataGridCell's Bound Value is Updated

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, mvvm, datagrid

All I have the following `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="resourceDataGrid" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
          GridLinesVisibility="None"
          RowHeaderWidth="0" 
          CanUserAddRows="True" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources, 
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                IsAsync=True}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="KeyIndex" Binding="{Binding KeyIndex}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="FileName" Binding="{Binding FileName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="ResourceName" Binding="{Binding ResourceName}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
       <controls:CollectionTextColumn Collection="ResourceStringList" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

when a row in the data set is removed I want to re-number the `KeyIndex` column. When this renumbering takes place I want to elegantly flash the updated cells letting the user know then these values were updated.

I am still relatively new to WPF and MVVM and I am unsure how to 'listen' for this change in value. My first thought was that I don't need a new `DependencyProperty` for this job, and could do this my merely hooking into the `SourceUpdated` property using a `DataTrigger` but it is not clear how to do this. I have attempted to define the following

```
<Style x:Key="readOnlyCellUpdatedStyle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="ContentUpdated" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" 
                                         Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="0.25" 
                                         Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But binding to a `ContentUpdated` property for each item in the ViewModel is far from ideal. **What is the correct way to do what I want?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SourceUpdated` is how I've done this in the past, but you need to make sure you've set `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` to true on the `Binding`. Something like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Template>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyIndex, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.SourceUpdated">
                                ...
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Template>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```